# How do I convert degree to hour and minutes

Tags: python

I want to create a function `abc(hours, add_minutes)`. The `hours` parameter is a list of vectors (e.g. `[0,1], [1,0], [-3,4]` and so on). The vectors represent a time in a clock. My approach is to find the angle between 2 vectors, and convert it to degrees. However, I'm confused as to how I would then extract hours and minutes from this.

A test would be `abc([-4,5], 15)`.

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy
def abc(hour, add_minutes):
    # width
    xval=hour[0]
    
    # height
    yval=hour[1]
    dotproduct = numpy.dot(xval,yval)
    theta = numpy.arccos(np.dot(xval,yval)/(numpy.linalg.norm(xval)*numpy.linalg.norm(yval)))
```

Comment: What is `hour_vector`?

Comment: It would help to have a working example.

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo while copying -pasting the code

Comment: use the vector to determine the angle from 0-360, and create a function that has 0-12 linearly mapped over 0-360 and just grab the hour in decimal form, then convert the decimal to minutes

Comment: do you mean hour = theta/30 and minute = theta/1800? @Derek

Comment: @IshaanSingh I was thinking about it slightly differently but, basically yes those end up being equal

Comment: I dont know where your answer went @DerekEden but what's //1 ?

Comment: // is floor division

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to convert the hour vector to the angle on 360-degrees (or 2pi radians, to be more precise) clock. First, I want to ensure that the clock is the unit circle.

```
temp = 1 / math.sqrt(hour[0]*hour[0] + hour[1]*hour[1])
hour[0] *= temp
hour[1] *= temp
```

Now we can compute the sine of the angle to noon. Note that it is the cosine to the 3 o'clock or the x-axis in our coordinates, i.e., the sine of the angle between the hour handle and the noon is `hour[0]`. We take inverse sine, i.e., arcsin or asin.

```
alpha = math.asin(hour[0])
```

`alpha` is between `-pi/2` and `pi/2`, i.e., it is in radians.

Almost there! We need to determine in which quadrant it is. We use the sign of `hour[1]` to do this.

```
if hour[1] <= 0:
   alpha = math.pi - alpha
```

We got the angle to the noon! Now we convert it to actual amount of hours. Note that 12 hours corresponds to `2pi` degrees, and we get ratio:

```
# x / 12 = alpha / (2*pi) 
# x = 12 * alpha / (2*pi) = 6 * alpha / pi
hour = 6 * alpha / math.pi
```

That's it.
UPD. Found a glitch, I corrected the code. The code may be combined (and shortened) as follows:

```
hour[0] /= math.sqrt(hour[0]*hour[0] + hour[1]*hour[1])
if hour[1] >= 0:
    hour = 6 * math.acos(hour[0]) / math.pi
else:
    hour = 6 - 6 * math.asin(hour[0]) / math.pi
```

Comment: itsnt there an easy formula to just convert degrees to hours and minutes ?